# iOS. Configure flurry to display ads with my concrete apps?

Tags: ios, ads, flurry, advertisement-server

For example playhaven allows to create a concrete set of applications to display. Even if they don't belong to me.

Is it possible to do the same with Flurry? It is hard to understand anything with their awful design. As I understand I must create "a new campaign" but it doesn't allow to advert with a zero budget/price

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking to serve direct sold ads using Flurry? If yes, you can create an 'Advertisers' campaign under the Publishers tab, and set the value in the price field as $0.01. There is a bug in the system which doesn't allow the value to be $0.00. However, since this value is only for your self-reporting purpose, it wouldn't affect ad serving.

For any further queries, please write to support@flurry.com.

(Full disclosure: I work in the Support team at Flurry)